# Extend android app features

Tags: android

I'm developing a simple application that has a few emoticons, and I want to make a functionallity that let people pay for new emoticons.
What's the best way to accomplish that? 
I've been reading about licensing but I'm not sure if that's what I need (I'm kinda new on Android programming)

Thanks in advance
Ezequiel

Answer (score 1):

I was looking in Android documentation, and the best approach seems to be In-App Billing 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

Answer (score 0):

In-App Purchase (IAP) will be the best way to implement pay for emoticons in your android app.

Here are some tutorials and examples to get you started.

https://blahti.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/how-to-add-in-app-billing-in-android-part-1/

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/implement-in-app-purchase-version-3

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1009240/How-to-Implement-Android-In-App-Purchases